# Linked list works in when everything is in 1 file but does not during modular programming

Tags: c, modular

I need to use a linked list in order to create a playlist of songs but when running the code it only takes my input but does not execute `Song_Print` function so I don't even know if the values entered were taken. When putting all the code in 1 c file it works but not in this modular form which I need it to be.

In `song.h` header file I have:

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H
struct song {
    char name[50];
    char artist[50];
    int duration;
    char genre[50];
    struct song* next_song;
    int ID_in_playlist;
};

void Song_New (void);
void Song_Print (void);
void init(void);


#endif
```

In `song.c` I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "song.h"

struct song *song = NULL;

void Song_New (void){
    
    printf("Type in your song name: ");
    scanf("%s", &song->name);
    
    printf("Type in your artist name: ");
    scanf("%s", &song->artist);
    
    printf("Type in your song duration (in seconds): ");
    scanf("%d", &song->duration);
    
    printf("Type in your song genre: ");
    scanf("%s", &song->genre); 

    return;
}

void Song_Print(void){
    
    printf("-----PRINTING YOUR SONG-----\n");
    printf("The song name: %s\n", song -> name);
    printf("The song artist: %s\n", song -> artist);
    printf("The song duration: %i\n", song -> duration);
    printf("The song genre: %s\n", song -> genre);

    return;
}

void init(void) { 
    
    song = (struct song *)malloc(sizeof(struct song));
    
    return;
}
```

In `main.c` file I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "song.h"

int main (void){
    
    init();
    Song_New();
    Song_Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `&` before the string variables in `scanf()`

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Run it under a debugger to see what it's doing when it should be calling `Song_Print`.

Comment: `song = (struct song *)malloc(sizeof(struct song));` should be simplified to: `song =malloc(sizeof(struct song));`  ([Not recommended to cast malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/645128))

Comment: `struct song *song = NULL;`  may be syntactically correct, but it is a confusing name for a symbol.  It would be better to choose different name for the pointer `song`

Comment: Thank you for the answers it works now!

Comment: `scanf("%s", &song->name);` is a run time error waiting to happen.  Use `scanf("%49s", &song->name);`